# Alternative to Eclipse for C and C++ development?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, ide, cross-platform

I have been using Eclipse for C and C++ development for some time. Unfortunately Eclipse has it's faults (speed, the crappy integrated console, and some bugs that pop up from time to time).

For C++ development Qt Creator is a very good choice, but I need something for both C and C++.

I don't really need the integration parts of the IDE (I don't need an integrated project manager, compiler or debuger). What I need is code navigation. Eclipse provides a great feature "callgraph for structure elements" that is unparalleled when I need to modify big crummy code bases (which is what I do most of the time).

Code completion and at least some integration documentation (doxygen, generic comments before functions, system documentation) is an absolute necessity.

Oh and the IDE has to be crossplatform.

Is there something other then Eclipse?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried NetBeans? There is a plugin for C/C++ development.

Comment: Netbeans aren't bad, but the callgraph feature is limited to functions only. :-/

Answer (score 21):

Check out [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) as an option.  Much lighter weight, updated constantly (via SVN nightlies), many of the same features as Eclipse.  C::B has Doxyblocks, a plugin for Doxygen.

Comment: Tried, but code navigation is just years behind Eclipse.

Comment: I'll admit that's a feature that I don't employ as often in an IDE.  There are lots of plugins, so perhaps one of those has the feature for which you seek.  Otherwise, no skin off my nose if you pick something else.

Comment: +1 for code::blocks. As a developer that's mostly been using visual studio in the past, when I decided to go cross platform I tried eclipse and found it far too slow, so now I'm using code::blocks on windows and linux and am pretty happy. Not saying it will tick all your boxes by any means.

Comment: +1 for code::blocks, as for eclipse? Never liked it for many reasons, mainly speed, which is appaling. Why would anyone want to develop native apps in something like Eclipse, Netbeans and now Very Slow 2010? I believe that the best way to develop native apps is in native IDE (for many reasons not only for speed), and code::blocks is really cool (much better in my personal opinion than Very Slow 2010 since the latter is now running under .Net which is slow and now Very Slow 2010 has unacceptable performance).

Answer (score 18):

Wow. I can't believe I'm the first person pointing to Emacs. ;-)

Comment: @jason -- vim *is* better.  (personal opinion, not statement of fact or intended as flame bait)  @let_me_be: Both emacs and vim are extremely powerful tools that provide all of the features you require.  Learning at least one of them well is a very good idea.  And if you're going to learn only one...vim is better ;)

Comment: @William -- vim is an excellent text editor, but there are a lot of better tools out there than Eclipse for editing text. Emacs is far enough along the "full development environment" curve that it is accused of being an operating system. I think that speaks volumes about how much closer it is to Eclipse.

Answer (score 17):

I like [qtcreator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/) which you can use without writing against [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com).

It is modern, nicely looking, cross-platform (ie on Windows, OS X and Linux), maintained / extended at a good clip, integrated with other tools (debuggers, revision control, ...).  Oh, and it is free.

Comment: As I already mentioned in the question, unfortunately QtCreator isn't suitable for C development.

Comment: Yes, QtCreator prefers C++ but you can still use it to edit C files so your downvote is a little harsh.  And QtCreator still gives you decent integration with the other components.  I don't think anything will give code analysis / navigation for both languages in a modern and cross-platform tool. If that is a must, stick with Eclipse.  FWIW I use Emacs cross-platform for many languages.

Comment: I use Qt in my daily routine for C++ and the parser from the latest nightly builds is very nice and fast.

Comment: But it's a C++ parser, right? Original question was about something that does C and C++, parses code structure, is free, cross-platform and integrated with other tools. Making coffee is optional.

Answer (score 10):

Take a look into KDevelop4. It is quite good

Comment: Navigation in Code::Blocks is not as "colourful" as Eclipse, but for C++ it can be quite effective. In KDevelop 4.2, in other hand, it is eve better. It lacks, unfortunately, a bit of maturity. Its worth a try anyway.

Comment: @fljx I agree. Unfortunately, it still has some issues, but it is much better then Kdevelop 4.0 was ;) Good thing is it's developer are working on it, and fixing bugs

Answer (score 7):

Hm, I'm kinda surprised, that noone mentioned [SlickEdit](http://slickedit.com).

I think everyone, who has ever used Visual Studio and who has migrated to Linux programming, has had this problem - what to use for C++ dev. Now I use SlickEdit and I'm pretty satisfied.

Here's a short quote from the official web-site:
`Welcome to SlickEdit 2010. SlickEdit 2010 is a cross-platform, multi-language code editor that gives programmers the ability to code in over 40 languages on 7 platforms. This latest version builds on the company’s 22 years of experience in enabling developers and development teams to create, navigate, modify, build, and debug code faster and more accurately`

[Here](http://www.slickedit.com/products/slickedit/features-by-language) you could see what features are supported by language (see that C/C++ has all possible features)

[Here](http://www.slickedit.com/products/slickedit/cool-features) You can see some of the cool features (and they are really cool) + examples + some demos (video).

[Here](http://www.slickedit.com/products/slickedit/new-features) is a list with the newest features.

Also, the debugger is pretty nice, it's kinda Visual Studio's debugger - easy to use and powerful (not as VS's of course, but it's still nice).

You can configure SlickEdit however you like. Yep, the options are too many, it seems too confusing, but this gives you the opportunity to change anything.

The problem is, that it is **not** free (in a legal way, at least.. ;) ), but you could download a trial to try it. I've tried some other products, and this one is the best to me.

I'd suggest you to try it, at least (:

Comment: Not cross platform...

Answer (score 6):

I currently use Vim with the [NERD Tree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658), tag list and [a](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=31) plugins. I'm pretty happy with the workflow using those plugins provide.

Answer (score 5):

Try with [codelite](http://www.codelite.org/)

It has a great codecompletion (better than eclipse)

It is small and fast and run in windows and linux

Other options are, qtcreator, kdevelop, codeblocks and ultimate++

Answer (score 4):

I think [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) could be a proper candidate to satisfy your requirements.

It can be something like a simple text editor or a fully integrated environment as you like.

You can add special modes created by Emacs community for any programming language and features like code completion or any kind of documentation. And there is a lot of alternatives of these modes. So you can choose.

You can customize almost everything about Emacs, like keyboard shortcuts that can be for any purpose you can imagine or indentations and colors, and take your customizations with one file to everywhere you like. (The **.emacs** file)

A lot of tools like gdb or grep or svn are or can be integrated in emacs so you can use them in a more efficent way than using from command line.

But it has downsides. Using emacs requires much more Linux knowledge than any other graphical environments. (I dont know how it feels using emacs in Windows ) It is hard to learn how to use Emacs and how to add features. So it is not suitable for anyone who doesn't like to get dirty.

Answer (score 3):

Try Source Navigator NG.  Helps see relationships among classes in class hierarchies, etc.  Code browser, as in, you can go back to where you were.  Give yourself 5 hours on this and see how it takes you.  It's helped me.
http://sourcenav.berlios.de/

Answer (score 2):

I've tried many Linux IDEs and came to conclusion that there is nothing better that Eclipse. Simply I always lacked some features that Eclipse offers in them. Maybe kdevelop comes close however I found the Eclipse's SVN plugin much more usable. Besides I use VIM for smaller/test projects. Maybe some day we'll see VC under Linux and will be a serious alternative ;-)

Comment: You're mistaking things. Linux *is* an IDE. Except that you have different programs for what is one big package in eg. visual studio: you have editors, debuggers, version control, documentation processors, build systems, code completion, and even editor macros (at least for emacs and vi). Moreover, it is quite easy to integrate them together. I use VS at work and find it great, but when it comes to integrating 3rd party tools it sucks. I use emacs at home with make, gdb, doxygen, mercurial and etags and I find it way more flexible for the same work done.

Comment: The qustion was about OP looking for alternatives for the Eclipse IDE. I suggested that there are few comparable alternatves (command line tools / vim / emacse are uncomparable because they feel different). How am I mistaking things?

Comment: they don't feel that different. My day to day work is the same whether I use VS or emacs + stuff.

Answer (score 2):

[MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) is a cross-platform IDE that supports code navigation. Although its primary focus is on C# development, the latest version also supports C/C++, including code completion.

Comment: _latest version also supports_ does not sound like a very mature feature

Answer (score 1):

KDevelop on Linux works quite well

(and I have added more here to make this reply longer than 20 characters)

Answer (score -3):

Since you didn't mention crosss platform as being one of your criterion why don't you download Visual Studio Express http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/
and be done with?

Comment: Quote from the OP's question: `Oh and the IDE has to be crossplatform.`.